# KKT in a nutshell graphically

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

## Objective

Confirm if the understanding of KKT is correct or not. Seek for further explanation and confirmations on KKT.

Reposting original at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255413) as suggested to seek answers from Math side.

### Background

Trying to understand KKT conditions, especially the complementary one, which always pops up out of blue in SVM articles. I do not need list of abstract formulas but do need a concrete, intuitive, and graphical explanation.

### Question

If P, which minimizes the cost function f(X), is inside the constraint (g(P) >= 0), it is the solution. It seems KKT is not relevant in this case.

[image]

It seems KKT says if P is not inside the constraint, then the solution X should satisfy below in the picture. Is it KKT all about or do I miss other important aspects?

[image]

### Other clarifications

- Should f(x) be convex for KKT to apply?
- Should g(x) be linear for KKT to apply?
- Should λ be necessary in λ*g(X) = 0? Why g(X) = 0 or g(Xi) = 0 is not enough?

### References

- [Lagrange Multipler KKT condition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239912)
- [Does every gutter point in SVM have positive multiplier?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244415)
- http://fnorio.com/0136Lagrange_method_of_undetermined_multipliers/Lagrange_method_of_undetermined_multipliers.html